# TestNG Custom Result

Tags: java, testng

I use testNG to run a test automation framework.  Currently I run through large suites of tests then post suite I iterate over the Results in a listener and add them to a mySQL DB that I use as a test dashboard.

IT works great but what I want to do now is take a screenshot when I hit a failure in my @test and add it to the result so in my listener I can process it.

something like this would be nice

```
@test
foo(){
  My Test hits an error I take screenshot = shot1
  ResultMap.add(customError=shot1)
}
```

then when I process all the results at the end of my suite in the listener I can say

If customeError =true write customError to my DB

Anyway to do anything similar to this

Comment: Hi @ducati how are you able to iterate over the test suite results after running your tests. could you show me your test listener implementation(Just a sample code). TIA!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out unless im missing something this seems to work and is almost to easy

```
ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
result.setAttribute("Name", "put my screenshot here");
```

In my @test I can just say if assert fails

```
ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
result.setAttribute("Name", "put my screenshot here");
```

My test listener has a if now to look for "Name" and if there get the value and put it in my DB.

Quick test looks good ill update this if it works when I code it all up for real

Answer (score 0):

There is a setAttribute method available with the ITestResult interface, which lets you set custom attributes.
You can probably add your error screenshots to a list, while your case executes.
In the afterInvocation method, you can check for the length of the array, if it has elements, then setAttribute of the result of method..something like..setAttribute("ErrorScreenshots", ErrorScreenshots[])

In your custom report, you can check for the attribute value and add it to the db as probably paths to where the screenshots are stored or as blobs if you want..

Comment: So I now see how to add to the context but im looking to add to the testResult.  Basically if the assert fails im going to want to add a new parameter or attribute to the current test object with my failed screenshot.   I have yet to find a way to do this